# How to debug without formatting the code in Javascript (ECMAScript 6)

Tags: javascript, debugging, ecmascript-6, redux

When using arrow functions and short functions in javascript (ECMAScript 6) debugging becomes difficult.

Normally i add `debugger`in my code or I add a breakpoint.
With the syntax above its not possible to debug without formatting the code.

```
export const submitDevice = passCode => dispatch => dispatch(addDevice(passCode)).then(dispatch(loadDevices());
```

Does anyone know a way to debug without formatting the code?

Comment: You would normally have to debug by setting a breakpoint(s) on either that line or inside `addDevice` and `loadDevices` and step through... As of now, there is no better way than that. Also, that's how normal debugging is done!?

Comment: Couldn't you add a breakpoint then just step in/out until you find yourself in the function you're looking for?

Comment: So, why put lots of code all on one line if you want to debug it?  Just put your code across multiple lines, use braces where needed and then you can insert a `debugger` command anywhere you need it.  Arrow function syntax should be used when it makes your life easier, not when it makes your life harder.  It's a tool.  Use the right tool for the job.  People seem to be in love with the brevity of arrow functions and then seem to forget they don't have to use them everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys.
Problem right now is that I don't want my code in one line like that. But my team loves this syntax and I don't think they want to change this. So I was searching for a solution.